# Kotlin flow replay

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-flow

Is there a way I can 'replay' the last emitted value for a certain subscriber instead of setting 'replay' to the producer?
I just want only a certain subscriber to get the replayed value and not the others. Thanks

Comment: StateFlow its a hot flow with replay 1  by default

Comment: I'm not using StateFlow... I'm using Flow.
And if I set 'replay' with 'shareIn', it works. But I don't want every subscriber to have the replay, just the ones that I need to.

Thanks

Comment: then use stateIn ,or make an extension function for the flow... that my answer .

Comment: an example would be really helpful, thanks.